# Increase Windows partition in a working dualboot

Tags: windows, 12.04, gparted

I have a dualboot with Precise and Windows 7, and the second partition has less space than the Ubuntu one. The Windows disk is almost full, so, is there a way to 'safely' resize them? Does GParted mess with the Windows partition?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use a live cd or usb version of ubuntu. Open gparted and change the size of the partion as needed. For me gparted never messed anything up.

Answer (score 0):

Gparted as always been useful as well for me, I'll vouch for the statement above, I have 3 partitions on my hard drive and constantly have to rearrange them to fit what I'm doing.
(havn't lost anything yet, though I'm sure it's bound to happen)